# Azure Storage 1.7 upgrade to latest getting error 400 bad request

Tags: azure-storage

We wanted to upgrade the azure storage from 1.7 to the latest version. Basically we have integration with windows desktop client installed that uploads to azure directly with Rest API with Shared Access key.

With 1.7 - windows desktop client request for upload to our API and we create a blob reference and generate a shared access signature and desktop client upload the directly.

Now if you are use latest version we use BlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(filename.ToString()) but with this token our desktop unable to upload the file and getting error 400 bad request.

We managed to find out that the desktop client needs to add request header x-ms-blob-type with value of BlockBlob and it works fine.

Our next release of the software will be able to fix the issue but current and older releases will be broken. Is there a way to send the header "x-ms-blob-type" with url back to desktop so the older version works without any code changes.

Please advise?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately send the header "x-ms-blob-type" with URI back won’t work as Azure Storage Service doesn’t take these headers via URI. You shall add all headers via the storage client library.